# Text editor for custom field in joomla

Tags: joomla1.5, joomla-extensions, joomla-template

I have created a custom field in Joomla 1.5 menu for description of the menu. I have edited the **component.xml** in `administrator\components\com_menus\models\metadata` but now I want to put a  text editor in place of a normal text-box. Any ideas how to approach this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create an element of editor type.

[Learn how to create element](http://docs.joomla.org/Creating_custom_template_parameter_types) and [how to save data](http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_use_the_editor_in_a_component#Save_the_data)

```
class JElementMyeditor extends JElement
{
    var $_name = 'Myeditor';

    /**
     * @param $name
     * @param $value
     * @param $node
     * @param $control_name
     */
    function fetchElement($name, $value, &$node, $control_name)
    {
        $editor = JFactory::getEditor();

        $width  = $node->attributes('width');
        $height = $node->attributes('height');
        $col    = $node->attributes('col');
        $row    = $node->attributes('row');

        //  ($name, $html, $width, $height, $col, $row, $buttons = true, $params = array())
        return $editor->display($control_name.'['.$name.']',
                                htmlspecialchars($value, ENT_QUOTES),
                                $width, $height, $col, $row,
                                array('pagebreak', 'readmore') ) ;
    }
}
```

And you can use this in xml as

```
<param  name="custom_param" 
        width="300" 
        height="150"
        type="myeditor" 
        label="LABEL"  
        description="DESC" 
        />
```

Comment: Sorry i didn't explain it correctly i have added the a extra field in Parameters (System) of each menu item this is the code
    `<param name="menu_descrption" type="textarea" size="90" rows="7" cols="40" default="" label="Menu descrption" description="descrption" />`
I want a text editor for this is there a way i have searched but didnt get anything