# How to insert default joomla texteditor in module?

Tags: joomla, module, editor

I need to create joomla 1.5 module with textfields wrapped with default texteditor. Could anyone help me, please? Here is my mod_...xml

```
<params>
    <param name="felicitation" type="text" default="Желаем хорошего настроения и счастья:)!" label="Текст поздравления" description="укажите текст поздравления" size="60">
    </param>
    <param name="message" type="textarea" default="Дорогой друг! От всей души поздравляем тебя с Днём рождения! Желаем благополучия, личностного самосовершенствования, достижения намеченных целей.Сотрудники Центра развития молодёжных волонтёрских программ." cols="30" rows="7" label="Текст письма" description="текст поздравления в письме">
    </param>
    <param name="image" default="" type="imagelist" label="Выберите картинку" description="" directory="images/stories" >
    </param>
</params>
```

Answer (score 0):

The editor field isn't part of the [standard field elements in Joomla 1.5](http://docs.joomla.org/Standard_form_field_and_parameter_types) although it is available in Joomla 2.5 and above.

In your case, you will need to create a custom parameter type. See [this response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8895052/text-editor-for-custom-field-in-joomla) on how to setup a custom field element for the editor.